# Kotlin on Android alters library variable instead of defining a new variable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

today I started a new Android project with Kotlin support. But as soon as I launch it on my phone, it is disconnected from Wi-Fi (Application has INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permissons but no socket code yet). Here is the code:

```
package org.arch.cast

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    internal var dummy = 10
    internal var channel = 20

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

After experimenting a bit I noticed that one of my variables wasn't marked as "not used" even though it was not used.

[image: Here is the screenshot of variables]

This is the only class the project contains right now, no other service or activity exists so nothing is referring channel variable anywhere in the project. I also added a dummy variable to show that it is marked as not used. I noticed that the problem was its name and it was actually not defining it but altering another variable from a library I didn't import. And since it was related to Wi-Fi, phone was disconnecting.

[image: Here is the screenshot of autocomplete]

Sure everything works when I change the variable name but this should not be the solution, it is only a temporary workaround. So the question is, how can I prevent Kotlin from altering the variable and make it actually define it in my class?

Comment: Your code does define your own variable, and is not modifying anything. The completion suggestion shows that there is a library type that you can use, but since you're initializing the variable with the value of 10, its type will be Int, and not the Channel type shown in the autocomplete popup. The wifi disconnections are not caused by your code.

Comment: @yole The thing is, simple socket code also works if I change the variable name, but doesn't work if I keep it as "channel" even though I dont use it anywhere.
var socket = Socket("10.0.0.10", 1010) on another thread.

Comment: Can you post the code as code and not as image please? Makes it easier to try it.

Comment: @leonardkraemer sure, i added the code now

Comment: First of all, there's no such thing as altering (overriding) variables (fields) in JVM code. The only way this could've gone wrong is if `AppCompatActivity` or any of its parents had `getChannel()` or `setChannel()` methods, but in this case the Kotlin compiler would've failed to compile your code because it expected the property to have the `override` modifier. I think the behavior you're observing is purely coincidental.

Comment: minimum viable example is actually just `class Clazz {
    var channel = 20
}` in an androit-kotlin project. I suspect it is a visuall bug in android studio. You cant ctrl-b to the usage.

Comment: @Egor setChannel and getChannel was what i meant with "altering" since Kotlin changes obj.setChannel(10) to obj.channel=10. But yes, as i experiment more, it seems coincidential to me too, it started workin when it is named "channel" now. I am asking since i am new to SO, do i mark it as solved now, or simply delete the question since it was a not a valid question?

Comment: @leonardkraemer uhm yeah, ctrl+b takes me to nowhere, only saying "No usage found in Project Files", it seems it is just a visual bug

Comment: @Israphel I'm not sure what you're calling a bug. The code completion behavior is exactly as designed.

Comment: @yole completion is okay, marking a non-used variable as used is not

Comment: @Israphel Highlightling of non-private variables in IntelliJ IDEA is performed optimistically: if the name of a variable has more than a certain number of occurrences in the codebase, IntelliJ IDEA can't check in real time whether any of them refer to the variable being highlighted, so it does not highlight it as unused